# Does KeyLines allow you to visually edit Neo4J graphs?

Tags: neo4j

I suspect that the answer is no, but I didn't see a definitive answer on their website.  Can you use [KeyLines](http://cambridge-intelligence.com/keylines/editions/) to connect to a remote Neo4J server, visually make editing changes such as adding nodes or relationships, and then saving them on the backend?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can.
Keylines offer a comprehensive API which you can use to read/write to the graph.
You can hook up events to create your own Cyper queries to perform write operations.